# Pop-up ad in wordpress blog, suspected malware attack

Tags: wordpress, popup, malware

My website is [www.thetechgears.com](http://www.thetechgears.com),a pop-up window opens up in the site leading to perfectmatch.com, but I am sure I haven't installed any ad-code, especially pop-up of this kind. I tried to figure out the location of the code but failed.

While the pop-up loads I could see some URL like anrdoezrs.net loading, this could be a hint in tracing.

Is the code located within database or somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to figure out the malware ad-code, but couldn't locate it. So, I just re-installed everything and made the installation more secure by using WordPress security plugins like "All In One WP Security", "Better WP Security" and "Wordfence Security"

But be cautious while tweaking settings of these plugins, as over-tweaking may lock-out the site for admins too. Before installing, take a backup of your .htaccess file

Answer (score 1):

Check your `.htaccess` file in the root of your WordPress installation. Normally, when your wordpress has been compromised attackers inject code into the .htaccess file, which will redirect your site to other sites.

If your `.htaccess` file is clean, then check your `index.php` and `header.php` in your theme folder and also the `index.php` in your root folder.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I have the same problem even after changing themes, I looked into `.htacccess`, and `index.php` file, they are clean, can I locate the pop-up trigger call and trace back to the code location?

Comment: When does this pop-up happen exactly? I visited your site, and it didn't show me any pop-ups.

Comment: The pop-up doesn't show if there is any Adblock extension installed in browser. When I click two or three links in the site, pop-up opens